# Построчная запись в файл из консоли

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть код:

```
 do {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("news.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine($"{ Console.ReadLine()}");
        }                         
    } while (Console.ReadLine() != "");
```

Нужно реализовать запись в `news.txt` по одной строке из консоли до того, как юзер пропустит строку, нажав Enter. Данный способ записывает почему-то не все строки, а именно пропускает каждую вторую

Answer (score 4):

Запрос на чтение и ожидание ввода выполняется при любом вызове `Console.ReadLine()`. В вашем случае проблема тут:

> while (Console.ReadLine() != "");

Эта введенная строка не будет записана.

Код изменить легко:

```
string newsLine;
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("news.txt", true))
{
    do
    {
        newsLine = Console.ReadLine();
        file.WriteLine(newsLine);
    }                         
    while (newsLine != "");
}
```

Comment: Ещё бы открытие потока вынести за цикл. Это ж тяжёлая операция.

Comment: да, чет тупнул, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Это же меняет поведение кода!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Да, но я бы сказал, что в лучшую сторону. Могу поспорить, что в открытии файла в цикле не было особой задумки, «просто так вышло».

Comment: В текущей постановке вопроса, изменения к лучшему, но в других сценариях изначальное открытие протока внутри цикла, позволяет не блокировать файл на долго.

Comment: В любом случае ждем автора и его комментариев, иначе - гадание на кофейной гуще